# API and "normal" URLs in one Yii2 application

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, yii2

I would like to have (use) in my Yii2 application:

- a standard, SEO-like URLs, with `.html` at the end (thus `'suffix' => '.html'`) and
- API request (basing on [very simple code](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)) without  this suffix.

So, to make my application being able to serve both `http://127.0.0.1/app/site/index.html`-like URLs and `http://127.0.0.1/uslabs/web/user/2`-like API calls.

It this possible? If so, how should I configure `urlManager` component for this?

I went through "[Quick Start](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)" chapter in "*RESTful Web Service*" section, but it bring no help. They don't use suffixes in examples given there. I'm stuck with the choice of either one or other scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Yii has a REST url router that you can use to associate with certain controllers, like this;

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'suffix' => 'html',
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'api',
            'suffix' => NULL],
    ],
]
```

See the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html) for more details

Comment: That sounds like a nice solution. However, you're repeating (as in Yii2 docs about REST apps), that I have to set `enableStrictParsing => true`. When I do this, my entire application dies -- I can't even access `appname/web` on my local environment. I'm getting `404` everywhere. I don't know, why and I don't know, why REST requires this param to be set, because it seems to be working without it (as "normal" application does). See [this forum post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/55979-yii2-rest-api-url-manager-problem/page__p__255132#entry255132) for details.

Comment: @trejder I just put that in because it's in the Yii example. Does the api work without it set?

Comment: To the point, where I managed to check so far (not beyond "_Quick Start_" page in "_RESTful API_" section) -- yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, on closer look, It seems, that your solution does not work. It seems that adding `suffix` in rule brings no change. I still must call my API via `http://127.0.0.1/app/web/json.html` even with `'suffix' => NULL` in place. In addition, according to [this Yii Forum post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/62923-api-and-%E2%80%9Cnormal%E2%80%9D-urls-in-one-yii2-application/page__pid__278172#entry278172), what I'm trying to achieve is possible, but tricky and hard and not encouraged. API calls should be handled by a separate application. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Yii Forum post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/62923-api-and-%E2%80%9Cnormal%E2%80%9D-urls-in-one-yii2-application/page__pid__278172#entry278172), what I'm trying to do is possible, but tricky and not encouraged.

API calls should be handled by a separate application. At [the end of "Quick Start" part](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html#summary) for API-like apps in Yii2 guide there's a suggestion:

> While not required, it is recommended that you develop your RESTful APIs as a separate application, different from your Web front end and back end for easier maintenance.